# Understanding params passed to the nodejs timezone plugin and alternative params possible to pass if any

Tags: node.js, timezone

I just came across [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timezone) package for timezones in nodejs. It seems to be quite powerful and gives accurate timezone related dates as can be seen when i run the very simple script in nodejs :-

```
var tz = require('timezone/loaded');

utc = new Date()

console.log('utc')
console.log(utc)

localTimeIN = tz(utc, '%c', 'en_GB', 'Asia/Kolkata')
localTimeTurkey = tz(utc, '%c', 'en_GB', 'Asia/Istanbul')
localTimeEurAmster = tz(utc, '%c', 'en_GB', 'Europe/Amsterdam')

console.log('localTime')
console.log(localTimeIN)
console.log(localTimeTurkey)
console.log(localTimeEurAmster)
```

I get the correct times and i can compare it vis-a-vis the international clock i have on my desktop. My question and problem so far is with the parameters. How many parameters does the function `tz` actually intake ? what is `%c` here ? as for param 1,3 and 4 they are clear to me after digging a bit into the source code of `node_modules` espically for the 4th param , you provide the `<continent>/<major_city_name>` and for the 3rd param i would like to stick with `en_GB` as i don't need localization for the given timezone.

Hence to summerize :-

1. What are all the possible parameters accepted by this function ?
2. What is the 2nd param in the `tz` function doing ?